# Will this catch block ever execute?

Tags: javascript

So is it possible that we can go into the second error block?
Given that we have some promise rejection or errors that happen in the logic section

```
somePromise
  .then(function(data) {
      //some logic
      return something;
    })
    .then((data) => {
      // more logic
    }, function(err) {
      // first error block
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // second error block
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible - if the second function passed to the `.then` throws an error (or returns a rejected `Promise`), the error will be passed down to the next `.catch`:

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(function(data) {
      //some logic
      throw new Error();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      // more logic
    }, function(err) {
      // first error block
      console.log('Handling first error');
      return err.somePropertyThatDoesNotExist.text;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // second error block
      console.log('Handling second error')
    });
```

As comment notes, the `catch` will also run if the *first* function passed to the second `.then` throws an error:

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(function(data) {
      //some logic
      return 'Foo';
    })
    .then((data) => {
      // more logic
      throw new Error();
    }, function(err) {
      // first error block
      console.log('Handling error in then');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // second error block
      console.log('Handling error in catch')
    });
```

Comment: IMHO I should also be called if the first function (`// more logic`) throws an error. The second function (`// first error block`) will only catch the previous errors, and not the ones in (`// more logic`)

Comment: Follow up question: is there any reason to writing it like that? Could we just make it work with one error handling function?

Comment: @nanomosfet No, not really - see [When is .then(success, fail) considered an antipattern for promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662289/when-is-thensuccess-fail-considered-an-antipattern-for-promises). You nearly always want to use `.catch` alone instead (and ensure that the `catch` itself doesn't throw anything).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the callback of `.catch` will be called if an error occurred in either the `// more logic` or the `// first error block` block.

`// first error block` won't be called for errors happening in `// more logic`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will catch the error in first block here is the below example for the same.

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw 'Ohh Nooo!';
});

promise1.then((data) => {
  // more logic
}, function(err) {
  // first error block
  console.log("Catch Error Block 1");
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
// expected output: Uh-oh!
```

Comment: Why do you write `// expected output: Uh-oh!`, if you show an example that outputs only `Catch Error Block 1`. And how does that answer the question. The OP is asking under which circumstance the `.catch(function(error) {` would be called.